# Hide 2 spans when neither is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 radio buttons, when radio button 'Up' is selected, it will show the 'productionUp' span and when radio button 'down' is selected, 'productionUp' will hide and the 'productionDown' span will show up.

I want both to hide when 'Same' is selected but I am not sure if what I have done is the most effecient way of doing it. Here is the HTML code

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Production</legend>
        <p>Was your production level in October versus September 2013....</p>
        <input type="radio" name="production-level" value="Up">Up<br />
        <input type="radio" name="production-level" value="Same">Same<br />
        <input type="radio" name="production-level" value="Down">Down
        <p>Note: PRODUCTION level meaning the level of overall production this month measured in units as compared  to last month.</p>

        <span id='productionUp' class='level'>
            <p>Production - Reasons why it is up. Click as many as apply.</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="production-why-up" value="Increase in demand">Increase in demand <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="production-why-up" value="Expected increase in demand">Expected increase in demand <br/> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="production-why-up" value="Fullfillment of past orders">Fulfillment of past orders <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="production-why-up" value="Increased marketing activity">Increased marketing activity <br/>
            Other: <input type="text" />
        </span>

        <span id='productionDown' class='level'>
            <p>Production - Reasons why it is down. Click as many as apply.</p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="production-why-down" value="Decrease in demand">Decrease in demand <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="production-why-down" value="Expected Decrease in demand">Expected Decrease in demand <br/> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="production-why-down" value="Technical difficulties in production">Technical difficulties in production <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="production-why-down" value="Shortage in raw materials">Shortage in raw materials <br/>
            Others: <input type="text" />
        </span>

    </fieldset>
```

The javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Production Level
    $("input[name = 'production-level']").click(function() {
        var production = $(this).val();
        var opposite = '';

        if(production == 'Up') { 
            opposite = 'Down'; 
            $("#production" + opposite).hide();
            $("#production" + production).show();
        }
        else if (production == 'Down') { 
            opposite = 'Up'; 
            $("#production" + opposite).hide();
            $("#production" + production).show();
        }
        else {
            $("#productionUp").hide();
            $("#productionDown").hide();
        }

    });
});
```

If you take a look on this one, you'll that I chose to hide both of them even though one is already hidden, I can't think of any other way to hide the selected one efficiently. Please advice.

```
else {
     $("#productionUp").hide();
     $("#productionDown").hide();
}
```

Comment: use two css classes one for show and one for hide

Comment: It does not matter.. what is wrong with it? You can always check visibility if you want but i can't see why you should do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or some kind of hard coding will do

```
else {
if ($("#productionUp").css('display') == 'inline') { // where i've figured that display is turning inline and none.
   $("#productionUp").hide();
} 
else if ($("#productionDown").css('display') == 'inline') {
   $("#productionDown").hide();
}
}
```

working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/Q34yv/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Production Level
    $("input[name='production-level']").on('change', function() {
        var production = this.value;
        if(production == 'Up') { 
            $(this).closest('fieldset').find(".level").hide();
            $("#production" + production).show();
        } else if (production == 'Down') { 
            $(this).closest('fieldset').find(".level").hide();
            $("#production" + production).show();
        } else {
            $(this).closest('fieldset').find(".level").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Try hiding with `.level` className which is common for both and showing with as you were doing but slight change is that to use `change` event instead of `click`.

Comment: I have many questions like this that has the class named 'level' declared as hidden from the beginning, using it will probably affect the other elements from other questions that uses the same class. 

Would you rather have me create unique classes per question to declare as hidden? I just want to clarify if it's the most effective way.

Comment: well in your case you can use `.closest()` method to find your class in a selected context.

Comment: Thank you man. So closest is used to basically find the class 'level' that is nearest or probably within the closest fieldset. Please correct me if I am wrong, I am still in the learning process of Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Show hide the span on radiobutton click

```
$('.level').hide();
$('input[name=production-level]').on('click', function () {
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    if (value == 'Same') {
        $('.level').hide();
    } else {
        $('.level').hide();
        $('#production' + value).show();
    }
});
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nesmar/77VHX/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use CSS?

```
input[value="Up"]:checked ~ #productionDown {
    display: none;
}
```

If you need IE8 and lower support (which don't know the pseudo-class selector `:checked`, you could toggle a class `.checked` for your radiobuttons with jQuery/vanillaJS.

```
.checked ~ #productionDown {
    display: none;
}
```

Here an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ttm6X/).

Comment: This doesn't work. Maybe because the spans are hidden as declared to begin with.